# What does "reaction rank" in Reaxys stand for?

Tags: databases

By exporting some search results from Reaxys, I found "Reaction rank" to be one of the columns in the Excel file. In my file, values descend from 107 to 52 and skip some values in-between too. Does anyone know what reaction rank stands for here?

Comment: Depending on how you exported this data, could it just be the sequential numbering of the reactions in your search results, after selecting the reactions you wanted? For example, you may have gotten 500 search results, but with some particular restrictions you exported only a few dozen results, specifically between hits 52 and 107.

Answer (score 3):

For the Elsevier's Reaxys data base, there is a [support page](https://service.elsevier.com/app/home/supporthub/reaxys/) you may consult without subscription, nor log-in to the product.  Actually, this is more like a searchable directory, too, because you search for keywords, like «rank», too.

Doing so [here](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12036/supporthub/reaxys/kw/rank/) -- time stamped 25/04/2019 -- offers insight about «How do I view my results?».  About half-way through this document, in subsection «Reactions. Order, limit or export your search results», the documentation states:

> "[Reaxys ranking] Defines the method of determining 'relevance'. To
>   change the sort type, click 'Reaxys Ranking' and define another sort
>   option: 'No of References', 'Reactant Availability', ‘Product
>   Availability'', ‘MW of product’, ‘Yield’ or ‘Publication Year’."

And because the content of columns of numeric content (like molar mass, number of reagents, year of publication) may be sorted, this may affect the presentation of the export, too.  It equally may explain the occurrence of gaps in the values you mention.